# How to create spawner in a row in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, spawn

I want to spawn 3 object horizontally and I want to spawn them randomly (for example in first spawn if blue is in the middle next it will be get positioned randomly and the other same as this one)
[image]

And here is the code I have now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {

public float min_X = -2.3f, max_X = 2.3f;

public GameObject[] colorobject;


public float timer = 2f;

void Start() {
    Invoke("SpawnObject", timer);
}

void SpawnObject() {

    float pos_X = Random.Range(min_X, max_X);
    Vector3 temp = transform.position;
    temp.x = pos_X;

    if(Random.Range(0, 3) > 0) {

        Instantiate(colorobject[Random.Range(0, colorobject.Length)],
        temp, Quaternion.identity);
        
    } else {

       //
        
    }

    Invoke("SpawnObject", timer);

}



} // class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to have a random integer value and a range. For example, if I decide the range between 0-6,if my number is between 0 and 1, I will spawn Red-Blue-Green;if it is between 1 and 2, I will spawn Red-Green-Blue. This may not be the best approach but the only one I can think of right now. You can use Random.Range for that as you have used it above :D

Comment: thanks for your attention and reply i am so glad . i know now what u say but my main problem is this : how can i tell that ? i will add that 3 color in inspector as a element for my array but i do not know how to tell my random.range get those object and spawn them

Comment: Well to spawn the objects, you can predefine the positions.If the 3 positions are at x=0,x=3,x=6 (assuming) then write codes for spawning the three objects in that order of RGB (if random = 0) and hardcode them. For random = 1, you will spawn in order of RBG. Like this you will get 6 if statements (thats why I implied it that it's not the best approach).Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: thanks i should test it . if i want to be more clear this game is like any other minimalistic game that playing with color i have a main player which is a cube and i want it to be changed after 10 sec for ex . if main player is blue 10 sec later it will be another color and also i need a randomizer for this too . then  the 2 color which are the same can be triggered and cube can go into the same color the other will lose you . ( and maybe i will add background color changer depending on cube color ... sorry its too much and long but this will be my game